# Select column from one table according to frequency of other?

Tags: mysql

How do I select columns from one table depending on the frequency of other column in other table

**Example:**

```
Table 1
```

---

```
sr.     id
1       37
2       45
3       56
3       69
2       25
```

---

```
Table 2
```

---

```
id
37
45
56
56
56
45
69
```

Expected result

---

```
sr    count
1      1
2      2
3      4
```

---

Now I need to select `sr` in order of the frequency of its ids in `table 2`.

Comment: what's your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following query does accomplish what you want:

```
SELECT 
  Table1.sr,
  COUNT(*) total
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
GROUP BY Table1.sr
ORDER BY total;
```

**More:**

Just in case, if you want all the `sr` from `table1` no matter whether the corresponding id exists in `table2` or not then you need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

So, here's the modified query based on this scenario:

```
SELECT 
Table1.sr,
COUNT(Table2.id) total
FROM Table1 
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON Table1.id = Table2.id
GROUP BY Table1.sr
ORDER BY total;
```

Comment: Make this `GROUP BY Table1.sr` and remove `DESC` from `ORDER BY` and the answer is perfect :-)

Comment: Thanks @ThorstenKettner. I've just skimmed over the question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
SELECT t1.sr, t1.id
FROM table1 AS t1
JOIN (
   SELECT id, COUNT(*) AS cnt
   FROM table2
   GROUP BY id
) AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
ORDER BY t2.cnt DESC
```

Comment: But how do I get the count of t1.sr in t2

Answer (score 0):

```
select t1.sr,count(*)
from take1 t1
inner join take2 t2 on t1.id =t2.id
group by t1.sr
```